# request.session.regenerate not working, undefined 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got this issue:

```
request.session.regenerate(function() {

                request.session.user = username;
                return response.send(username);
});
```

When logging in I always get undefined error:

```
Cannot read property 'regenerate' of undefined
```

If I just leave `return response.send(username);` it works fine, however I need to create a session.

What could be the issue?

**More code**

```
router.post('/login', bodyParser, function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;


    adminUser.findOne({
        username: username
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err | data === null) {
            return response.send(401, "User Doesn't exist");
        } else {
            var usr = data;

            if (username == usr.username && bcrypt.compareSync(password, usr.password)) {

                request.session.regenerate(function() {

                request.session.user = username;
                return response.send(username);

                });
            } else {
                return response.send(401, "Bad Username or Password");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Added: `app.use (session());`

Now its working.

Comment: Are you using `express`?

Comment: @doublesharp jep `var express = require('express');var router = express.Router();`

Comment: What are you using for session management? [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)? Without more code the only thing to say is that `request.session` isn't being set.

Comment: @doublesharp added the whole function, maybe session is the problem, please take a look

Comment: Express does not automatically have `request.session`.  You have to be using some middleware that creates that like `express-session`.

Comment: @jfriend00 added `app.use (session());` is working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it appears to have solved your issue...

Express does not automatically have `request.session`. You have to be using some middleware that creates that like express-session.  If you are using express-session, then you would add:

```
const session = require('express-session');
```

and

```
app.use(session({secret: 'my super secret'}));
```